# Cannot access global variable in one .c file from another .c file

Tags: c, global

To set the scene here - I have 2 .c files, call it `a.c` and `b.c`.

I then have 2 header files for each .c file, `a.h` (which has all function prototypes, and all global variables declared as `extern type name;`), and `b.h` which has only function prototypes of `b.c` as `b.c` contains no global variables.

I want to access `a.c`'s global variables in `b.c`, so I have added a statement `#include "a.h"` in `b.c`.

Only problem is, I still can't access `a.c`'s global variables in `b.c`, for example if I want to print. I have a global variable `int i;` in `a.c`, and if I do:

`i = 5;`
`printf("%d", i);` in `b.c`, I get an error saying that variable i has not been declared. What am I doing wrong?

The code:

a.c:

```
#include "b.h"

int i;

int main() {
    executeMethod();
    return 0;
}
```

b.c:

```
#include "a.h"
void executeMethod() {
    i = 10;
    printf("%d", i);
```

a.h:

```
int main();
extern int i;
```

b.h:

```
void executeMethod();
```

makefile:

CFLAGS=-Wall -g

```
all: main

main: a.c b.c a.h b.h
    gcc  $(CFLAGS) -o main a.c b.c a.h b.h

clean:
    rm -f main
```

Have also tried without the makefile:
    gcc -o main a.c b.c a.h b.h

Thanks.

Edit: it works if I define `extern int i;` on top of my `b.c` file, but say I have 60 variables, I would rather have them in a header.h file and just `#include "header.h"` rather than writing 50 extern statements.

Comment: You need to post your code so we can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: It would be great if you could enclose a [mcve]?

Comment: I have read that - and other sources. Some sources suggest I could achieve this using header files and that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Barmar I have done so now.

Comment: Important question - how are you compiling/linking it? Makefile?

Comment: @t0mm13b Yes. I will also edit my makefile into the OP.

Comment: `
main: a.o b.o
    gcc  $(CFLAGS) -o main $^
`

Comment: `gcc -E` should give you a clue on how the C compiler pre-processes the output. What version is the compiler? I have tried it here with gcc 4.9 and do not get the error.

Comment: @t0mm13b Strange! Also 4.9. It says (in my b.c class) that i has not been declared when I do i = 10;.

Comment: @t0mm13b I am ever so confused. Make a new directory, copied and pasted all the files, ran the makefile and it compiled in the new directory with 0 errors. Still doesn't run in the old directory. What the hell is up with that...?

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and include the header with the ext in both files.  Put the definition and initialization in the file that owns the variable.  This is okay:

```
extern int aaa;
int aaa = 1;
```

Comment: Can you please clarify how this answers the quesiton? OP claims that `extern int i` is already present in the included header but still getting compilation error.

Comment: Yeah, what @AlanAu said.

Comment: He added an edit "Edit: it works if I define extern int i; on top of my b.c file"